# Authenticate to Azure Active Directory by .NET Core web api from Front-End from different domain

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that is able to authenticate to Azure AD. If a user tries to execute an endpoint he is redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and then he is able to use the API.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority += "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsDomains"].Split(';', tringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                    });
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddSingleton<IOAuthTokenClient, OAuthTokenClient>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationProvider, AppAuthenticationProvider>();
        }

        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Now we are trying to connect to this API by JS from a DIFFERENT DOMAIN. I have problems in understanding how this JS should authenticate with this API (as a user in Azure AD). When JS calls the endpoint it gets redirect but Chrom blocks it as CORS request...

> VM55:5 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3912a795-6h78-446d-8548-a49ffd73f550/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=9f58a774-a9dc-4e6b-83cd-8967d3aeb0ec&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fourapi.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637203035634363596.YmIzYTgxNjctMjNhYy00OWE4LWFmYmEtMWRhZTM5MDAzZWQwYjA5MTdiZGMtZGI4OS00YTYwLTliN2EtNThiMWE5MmQ0Njcy&state=CfDJ8JU16Qc5LiRIl-KmHX3n1UK07_IvDsK1bEHExzX3MFzbLibzoctAms4RnZEV9W1G4g45SiKBQFGLiOWjDBUSerYBOPZ2fYloPvNbi2iDwwMdVTlGnTyD6wQpujGOxZx3VmpSlDaxokrmxLnQfomPapUFm6YFRBBM8G9zBu-Nd8_No2rjK1hhThHGcYWNKudJhzaWLqv23fcrn1JdZA1YmUl1Sj2Q6ZTq_gtzJjWmzHDmqzitqTKg0hqsXXZJ6LpyDMto89A0Qhg7akGix-xgXPKGXmTBZ_nmp3DceHTK94YDqBCe9AlDVUjp1OW0WfNiLN1ILve7K1mvPN1w2zPThgurMRzMkQ4TkC0Yzfi5QodGjWFN6FBeeF6YMpbn9YM-WjMgWRZyjAGQ9syW22bbvv5sEEMuNcW2AB6iMn4jV9hZ2u7tiAKM9lN6-MlZDrPdoGeexgR7uAmvJMcBhlam7LP_RbgJLp2FaPLNmKioYDjxV65fSX3ApZDLeB-dZfx34Q&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0'
>   (redirected from
>   'https://ourapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Users/jan.kowalski@ourdomain.com/Calendar/Events?startDate=2020-03-20T00:00:00Z&endDate=2020-03-21T00:00:00Z')
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8181' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

We can enable issuing access tokens in Authentication section in the Azure Portal and thanks to that, JS would be able to get access token on its own but I do not know if this is a correct way to do this. Maybe it is possible to somehow authenticate to Azure AD by calling our API?

Comment: You'll need to use `AddAzureADBearer` instead of `AddAzureAD`. Front-end JS apps don't play well with interactive authentication requiring back-ends. Your front-end needs to handle authentication with MSAL.js and send tokens with the requests that your API validates.

Comment: Hmm, so this approach with JS authentication on its own. Ok, thank you.